# Babel-traverse inclusion of root node

Tags: babeljs

I'm using `babel-traverse` in code that tries to find the name of the nearest function, class, or variable. Sometimes a function name is one step away, like `var foo = function() {}`, but also cases where the function is named directly like `function foo() {}`.

I'd like to have something like my current code:

```
node.traverse({
  ClassDeclaration: function (path) {
    comment.kind = 'class';
    path.stop();
  },
  Function: visitFunction,
  FunctionExpression: visitFunction,
  ArrowFunctionExpression: visitFunction,
  TypeAlias: function (path) {
    comment.kind = 'typedef';
    path.stop();
  },
  VariableDeclaration: function (path) {
    if (path.node.kind === 'const') {
      comment.kind = 'constant';
      path.stop();
    }
  }
});
```

But for the call to `traverse` to include the `node` itself in the first traversal pass. Is there a way to do this?